# Subsetting an element of a list based with an 'if'

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I am trying to extract the index of an element in a list that says the word "FAILED".

In my application, I am looking to extract the specific element because I want to apply some regular expression to get some info regarding the FAILED status.

```
test_list = ["This is a test element", "This is a FAILED test element"]

if any("FAILED" for x in test_list):
    failed = x
    end_line = test_list.index(failed)
else:
    end_line = test_list[-1]

print(end_line)
```

I want x to == test_list[1] or x == 1.. In my application, I won't know the index of where "FAILED" will occur.

This is the error: `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`

Comment: the `x` only exists in the comprehension's scope, but also notice that even if it worked, your condition will always be true as you are basically checking if `"FAILED"` is `True`. change to `any("FAILED" in x for x in test_list)`

Comment: I have added an answer, Hope it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
test_list = ["This is a test element", "This is a FAILED test element", "x", "y"]

for i, x in enumerate(test_list):
  if "FAILED" in x:
    end_line = test_list[i]
    break
else:
    end_line = test_list[-1]

print(end_line)
```

**Output**

```
This is a FAILED test element
```

Comment: try running it with `test_list = ["This is a test element", "This is a FAILED test element", "x"]` and see what happens. In short, the `else` will **always** execute after the loop. Not sure it's what you want

Comment: Oops, that break statement. Updated

Comment: yep now it's ok. In that case consider to just move the `end_line = test_list[-1]` **before** the loop, as a default value

Comment: This is the solution I used. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **list-comprehension**. The following code shows all the index where the substring `FAILED` is present.

Code:

```
test_list = ["This is a test element", "This is a FAILED test element"]

output = [i for i, string in enumerate(test_list) if 'FAILED' in string]
print(output)
# [1]
```

Answer (score 1):

variable x loses it's scope once it exists

`any("FAILED" for x in test_list)`

you can do,

```
temp = ""
for x in test_list:
    if "FAILED" in x:
        failed = x
        end_line = test_list.index(failed) 
        break
.... #your code..
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting such error since the scope of `x` is limited to the generator in which it is used -- namely the one you're passing to `any(...)`.
You could go with something like this:

```
test_list = ["This is a test element", "This is a FAILED test element"]
end_idx = -1
for i, x in enumerate(test_list):
     if "FAILED" in x:
            failed = x
            end_idx = i
end_line = test_list[end_idx]
```

With this you also avoid making another access to the list to get the index of `failed` with `.index(...)`